# Editing a has_one association in ActiveAdmin - avoid saving when nothing is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've got a model in which a very small percentage of the objects will have a rather large descriptive text. Trying to keep my database somewhat normalized, I wanted to extract this descriptive text to a separate model, but I'm having trouble creating a sensible workflow in ActiveAdmin.

My models look like this:

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :long_description
end

class LongDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :person_id
  belongs_to :person

  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

Currently I've created a form for editing the Person model, looking somewhat like this:

```rb
  form do |f|
    ...
    f.inputs :for => [
                      :long_description,
                      f.object.long_description || LongDescription.new
                     ] do |ld_f|
      ld_f.input :text
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

This works for adding/editing the LongDescription object, but I still have an issue: I'd like to avoid validating/creating the LongDescription object if no text is entered.

Anyone with better ActiveAdmin skills than me know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using `accepts_nested_attributes_for :long_description`? If so, you can add a `:reject_if` option:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :long_description
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :long_description, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['text'].blank? }
end
```

Note that this is a Rails thing, not an ActiveAdmin thing, and so it will simply skip assignment and update/create of the nested object if that attribute is missing.

More here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: Wonderful, that did the trick! I was indeed using accepts_nested_attributes_for, but I did not even consider that it might have an option like :reject_if. Thanks!

Comment: I added a related question, regarding automatically deleting the associated object again, in case you feel like pitching in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20742041/editing-a-has-one-association-in-activeadmin-destroying-when-attribute-is-blank