# Editing a has_one association in ActiveAdmin - destroying when attribute is blanked

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I've got a model in which a very small percentage of the objects will have a rather large descriptive text. Trying to keep my database somewhat normalized, I wanted to extract this descriptive text to a separate model, but I'm having trouble creating a sensible workflow in ActiveAdmin.

My models look like this:

```rb
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :long_description

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :long_description, reject_if: proc { |attrs| attrs['text'].blank? }
end

class LongDescription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :text, :person_id
  belongs_to :person

  validates :text, presence: true
end
```

Currently I've created a form for editing the Person model, looking somewhat like this:

```rb
  form do |f|
    ...
    f.inputs :for => [
                      :long_description,
                      f.object.long_description || LongDescription.new
                     ] do |ld_f|
      ld_f.input :text
    end

    f.actions
  end
```

This works for adding/editing the LongDescription object, and it avdois validating/creating the LongDescription object if no text is entered.

What I'd like to achieve is to also be able to remove the LongDescription object, for example if the `text` attribute is ever set to an empty string/nil again.

Anyone with better Rails or ActiveAdmin skills than me know how to achieve this?

Comment: you have `reject_if: reject_if:` in your example, which I assume was a typo?

Comment: If you have `validates_presence_of :text`, your database shouldn't ever get in a state where the `text` attribute is nil.

Comment: Yes, sorry. That was a typo.

Comment: I know I can avoid `text` being nil, yet in some instances I may have entered some string into `text` and thus having created a LongDescription object. The thing is I want that object to be destroyed if the contents of `text` is removed while editing the person object.

Comment: I want to make use of the extra model as transparent to the user as possible, and also avoid keeping empty `long_description` rows around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems like an awfully unusual architecture decision, but the implementation is pretty simple:

```
class LongDescription < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :text, on: :create

  after_save do
    destroy if text.blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: Wouldn't this conflict with the `:reject_if` option?

Comment: That seems likely. The `Person` object shouldn't be doing validation for its associated objects anyway, so you should remove the `:reject_if` condition.

Comment: As I mentioned only a very few Person object would actually have a long description, so I'd really like to avoid creating empty LongDescription objects every time I edit a Person.

Perhaps I'm completely off here, as you imply. Do you have any thoughts on how you'd go about this whole problem?